# COUNT() is selecting number of rows in table

Tags: php, mysql, count

My `COUNT(*)` in the query below is selecting the count of the number of rows in the table `users` rather than the number of rows where `distance` is less than 50.

Please can you tell me why the query is selecting the number of rows in the table `users` rather than the number of rows where the distance is less than 50?

Thanks in advanced.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 51.61050836267012 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( longitude ) - RADIANS( - 0.23701071739196777 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 51.61050836267012 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) 
AS distance
FROM  `users` 
AS `u`
HAVING distance <=50
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Or how are your results incorrect?

Comment: The COUNT(*) is returning 15 rather than the amount of rows where the distance is <= 50 (3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HAVING` should be related to `GROUP BY` expression. To restrict number of rows to a given criteria use `WHERE distance <= 50`

Comment: `distance` isn't a field name in the table `users`, it's just a value generated from the (6371 * acos(....)) function

Comment: yes, but you've used it as an alias for second projection element and you can refer to it in `WHERE` clause

Comment: PHPMyAdmin seems to disagree: `Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 0):

`HAVING` works on aggregated values (such as sum(column) **having** a certain condition) 
You should use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` in your case

Comment: It won't let me use `distance` in the WHERE clause as it's not a field name

Answer (score 0):

The having clause doesn't filter on rows like a where clause would for your count function. Try using a subquery instead.